# How to Get Current Product ID

Tags: laravel

My Product Controller. Here one Product has many images. Laravel one to many relationships working here. When I'm Create a new product and the product have 3,4 or many images. Product Image table has 2 columns, `Product_id` & `Image Name`.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'model'=>'required',
            'brand'=>'required|numeric',
            'category'=>'required|numeric',
            'subcategory'=>'required|numeric',
            'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
            'price'=>'required|numeric',
            'description'=>'required',
            'feature_image'=>'required|image|max:3000',
            'product_images'=>'required|max:5000',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('feature_image');
        $slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        $tempName = $slug . '-' . $currentDate . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = 'backend/images/product/';
        $imageName = $path . $tempName;
        $image->move($path, $imageName);
        $store_id = Store::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        $product_id = Product::latest()->first();

        $product = new Product();
        $product->user_id = Auth::id();
        $product->store_id = $store_id->id;
        $product->brand_id = $request->brand;
        $product->category_id = $request->category;
        $product->subcategory_id = $request->subcategory;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->slug = $slug;
        $product->model = $request->model;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->discount = $request->discount;
        $product->feature_image = $imageName;
        $product->pending = true;
        $product->visible = true;
        foreach ($request->product_images as $data){
            $productImageTempName = $slug . '-' . $currentDate . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $data->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $productImageName = $path . $productImageTempName;
            $data->move($path, $productImageName);

            $product_image = new ProductImage();
            $product_image->product_id = ????;
            $product_image->image = $productImageName;
            $product_image->save();
        }
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.product.index')->with('success', 'Product Successfully Create');
```

Now How I get Product id where Question Mark. I need the Product id which currently creating.

Comment: `$product->id` will be your product if after `save()` it will generate

Comment: $product->save();
$product_id= $product->id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save the product before its images, not only to get product's id, but also for data base foreign key constraint

and also you should do it inside a transaction to guarantee the data integrity

```
  // .....
  $product->visible = true;
        DB::transaction(function ()use($product,$request,$slug,$currentDate,$path){
            $product->save();
             foreach ($request->product_images as $data){
                 $productImageTempName = $slug . '-' . $currentDate . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $data->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $productImageName = $path . $productImageTempName;
                 $data->move($path, $productImageName);

                 $product_image = new ProductImage();
                 $product_image->product_id = $product->id;
            $product_image->image = $productImageName;
            $product_image->save();

        }
```